# German idiom for 'part and parcel'?

Tags: idiom

Google translate says 'Teil und Paket'. I was hoping you guys might be able to do better

Edit: the context would be something like 'the daily commute is part and parcel of city life.'

Comment: can you give some more context? the verbatim translation would be `Teil und Paket`

Comment: Next time you may want to try some other dictionary and not Google translaste which is wrong very often and not designed to translate single words without context.

Comment: Try better: http://www.dict.cc/englisch-deutsch/to+be+part+and+parcel+of+sth.html or http://www.linguee.de/englisch-deutsch/uebersetzung/be+part+and+parcel+of+sth..html

Answer (score 2):

*Part and parcel of* is

> Ein fester Bestandteil (+ Gen) ... sein

or

> Ein fester Bestandteil von (+Dat.) ... sein

Comment: Hmm that sounds about right! Vielen dank. So I suppose, die tägliche pendeln ist ein fester Bestandteil von dem Großstadtleben.

Comment: @Rascalniikov You would normally either hear *...des Großstadtlebens...* or *...vom Großstadtleben...*, but rather not *...von dem...*"

Comment: @Rascalniikov, and it is "das Pendeln"